# PostgreSQL and queue commands

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to know if there is a way to quere my queries. I am doing some basic text matching in psql and each query (which is saved in a different script) takes about 6 hours to run. I was wondering if there is a way to queue my scripts?

For example;

my database is called; "data"

my scipts are called; cancer, heart, death

and I am doing the following;

```
 data; \i cancer;
 data; \i heart;
 data; \i death;
```

But I have to come back every so often and check whether it is running or not etc which doesn't seem very efficient.

I am new to postgresql so appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the most easiest/fastest solution I can think of, but should work for your case ;)

When using psql from command line, you can start it with

```
-f filename
```

where filename is a SQL script. It will run the query and send the output to stdout. Also you can forward this to a file. Just put your queries into that SQL-file and you got your own queuing.

Assuming you might run Linux, you could use screen to have a simple way to leave your session open when logging of for the night.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution was to create a separate sql file which runs through the commands sequentially.